# Create a redirect based on date entered in a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect

I have a form that will have some checkboxes with different data options along with a text field for dates to be entered.

The logic for the date text field is that if the date entered is before 5/15/12 then they will be directed to page A after form submission OR if the date entered is after 5/15/12 then they will be directed to page B.

When the user selects the checkboxes and enters the date then they will be directed to specific pages after form submission.

So far I have the checkboxes working where depending on what they have selected they will be directed to specific pages. Now I need to figure out how to use the same logic for the date text field but I have no idea how to do so.

```
JS
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {

    //use instead of return false
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('.milk').is(':checked') && $('.butter').is(':checked')){
        // Butter and milk selected
        window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
    } 
    else if($('.butter').is(':checked')){
        // Only butter selected
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    }   

});

});


HTML
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST"> 
<div align="center"><br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" class="milk" value="Milk"> Milk<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" class="butter" value="Butter"> Butter<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" class="cheese" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to measure the date with Javascript, and get a diff, and you will have a number in milliseconds or days or something depending on how you convert the dates `(var d = diff(dateA, dateB))`.

Then you take [d] and put it through a switch

```
switch(d){
  case >5: gt_five();
  case 5: five();
  case <5: lt_five();
  default: def();
}
```

Keep in mind this is pseudo code, and the case statements don't make sense, but they should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe (via [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)):

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
  var inputDate = Date.parse( $('#myform:datefield').val() );
  var dateX = new Date(2012, /* Notice 5-1 here -> */ 4, 15); // 5/15/2012

  if (inputDate > dateX) {
      // do this (after date X)
  } else {
      // do that before X
  }
}
```

And somewhere in your markup:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" ...>
  <input type="text" id="myform:datefield" value="" />
  <button type="submit">GO!</button>
</form>
```